When does the Public Beta start?
For a while it was always coming in the next few hours, and now it just says "soon."  Does anyone know when the public beta is planned to start?

I was tempted to post an answer simply stating, "Soon :-)"

vote to close, now outdated :)

The site will launch at about 2011-09-07T19:19 UTC :)
From the announcement:

After just 9 days in private beta, we've already got 193 users who have asked
  191 questions and written 414 answers.

Congrats, folks!

Sites typically advance from private to public beta on Tuesday or Wednesday, but this is not automated. It takes manual intervention to transition to public beta. Monday being a holiday in the US, everyone's schedule is a bit off. 
The site will launch "soon."
